SQL code to calculate amount based in parent child relationship



account
code
amt




abc
x
123


abc
y
456


efg
x
321


efg
y
654


sdf
x
123


sdf
y
345


sdf
z
234



x is the parent code and y and z are the child code, if same account is present for both parent and children, I want to calculate parent amount = parent.amt - child.amt or if more than one child is present then  parent amount  = parent.amt - (childy.amt + childz.amt)
I tried selecting the two children records and then Union with one child record.. but it is also selecting the duplicates,even this condition is also not working having count(distinct code) = 1 )
Desired Output



account
code
amt




abc
x
333 (amt.x - amt.y)


efg
x
333 (amt.x - amt.y)


sdf
x
456 (amt.x - (amty + amt.z)




?? For account='abc' the value (amt.x - amt.y) = 123-456 = -333 and not +333.

SELECT t1.*, 
       t1.amt - COALESCE(t2.amt, 0) AS parent_amount
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t1.account = t2.account AND t1.code = 'x' AND t2.code = 'y'

The table must contain then next constraint:
UNIQUE (account, code)



I have updated my question above with the data and desired output – Shweta Srivastava

Maybe, you need in this:
SELECT account,
       'x' code,
       SUM(CASE code WHEN 'x' THEN amt ELSE -amt END) amt
FROM test
GROUP BY account;

fiddle

Thank you @Akina, but I have a scenario where two children are present, I tried giving distinct count of the code but its not working and selecting the duplicates

@ShwetaSrivastava Please provide sample data and desired output with the explanations for it according to Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, #5 and #3. Show all possible variants in the sample data.

Hi @Akina, I havae updated my question above with the data and desired output

@ShwetaSrivastava See 2nd variant.
